# world edge in cocos2d for iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

i have set my game's world (cocos2d- b2world) edges such as this :

```
-(void)worldEdge
{
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
    groundBodyDef.position.Set(0,0);
    b2Body *groundBody = world->CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);
    b2PolygonShape groundBox;
    b2FixtureDef boxShapeDef;
    boxShapeDef.shape = &groundBox;
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, 0));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(0, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0, winSize.height+100/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(winSize.width+100/PTM_RATIO, winSize.height+100/PTM_RATIO));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(winSize.width+100/PTM_RATIO, winSize.height+100/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, 0));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
}
```

my iphone is in portrait mode, and some how, i dont have edges on the top, but on the ground i do, and on the left side i have but on the right side i dont.

it seems that i dont understand something about the world edges, can some one help me change it so that the bottom will be "edge free" , but the right will have an edge ?

thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have got it.
as the answer above me described, this is how i do that:

```
// bottom edge
groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(width,0));
groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox);

// top edge
groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,height), b2Vec2(width,height));
groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox);

// left edge
groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,height), b2Vec2(0,0));
groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox);

// right edge
groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(width,height), b2Vec2(width,0));
groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox);
```

when in each edge we have : (from point, to point) when each point is a vector.

Answer (score 1):

In cocos2d ccp(0,0) placed in Bottom left corner.

```
 -(void)worldEdge
{
CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
groundBodyDef.position.Set(0,0);
b2Body *groundBody = world->CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);
b2PolygonShape groundBox;
b2FixtureDef boxShapeDef;
boxShapeDef.shape = &groundBox;
groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,winSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO));//for Top edge
groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(0, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO));//for Left edge
groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, 0), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO));//for Right
groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);

groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
}
```

Comment: For retina compatibility you should call the winSizeInPixels